# "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources" not found

Tags: .net-core, async-await, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I'm trying to create an integration test in .NET Core 2.1 with the latest Visual Studio 2017 build. There is nothing special about my setup whatsoever.

If I put the "async" keyword on a test, as is needed to test async methods, VS will terminate before attempting to run any tests with a FileNotFound exception. The missing file is "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources".

So the question (other than 'how does Microsoft keep managing to release such broken frameworks') is: Why?

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ServiceClients.IntegrationTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SicklyUnitTest
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
        }

        // This is fine
        [TestMethod]
        public void TrueIsTrue()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        // This causes FileNotFound - "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources"
        [TestMethod]
        public async void DeOmnibusDubitandum()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Framework is not broken. You are writing bad code. Avoid `async void`. Use `public async Task DeOmnibusDubitandum()` You should also check to make sure you have the correct versions/ packages referenced.

Comment: `async void` are fire and forget, so it is being invoked before anything else in the test has had time to be invoked, thus the error.

Comment: None of that is pertinent to my question. Please stay on topic. The framework is producing a FileNotFound exception, and that is most certainly inappropriate for any situation.

Comment: and what happens when you try it with a Task instead of void?

Comment: Where do you see the exception? When I run your test I get a warning `Method DeOmnibusDubitandum defined in class ServiceClients.IntegrationTests.SicklyUnitTest does not have correct signature. Test method marked with the [TestMethod] attribute must be non-static, public, return-type as void  and should not take any parameter. Example: public void Test.Class1.Test(). Additionally, if you are using async-await in test method then return-type must be Task. Example: public async Task Test.Class1.Test2()`

Comment: Also can you add which `NuGet` packages and versions you are referencing please? e.g. `Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK`, `MSTest.TestAdapater` and `MSTest.TestFramework`